Energy estimate for wave equation with lower power
Let us consider a wave equation with Dirichlet zero boundary condition, that is $u_{tt}+u_t=\Delta u+f(u)$, where the unknown $u=u(t,x)$ is a real function on $[0,T]\times 
 D$, $D$ is a regular domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and the Laplacian is taken w.r.t $x$. It is well known that we can rewrite it as $u_t=v,\quad v_t=-v+\Delta u+f(u).$
Consider the standard Lebesgue space $L^2(D)$, equipped with the usual inner product and norm. I need to give some estimates on $||\nabla u||^p$. For $p=2$, it is well known that $(u,\Delta u)=-||\nabla u||^2$ and $\frac{d}{dt}||\nabla u(t)||^2=-(\Delta u(t),v(t)).$ However, if $0<p<2$, I cannot construct a form of $||\nabla u(t)||^p$. Who can give me some help of estimating $||\nabla u(t)||^p$?
In fact, I am working with a stochastic PDE in which situitation $\mathbb{E}|\nabla u(t)|^2=\infty$ but $\mathbb{E}|\nabla u(t)|^p<\infty$ for some $0<p<2$. I think this is a pure PDE question.
Any comments or recommendation of reference is welcome!

Are you sure it is $|\nabla u|^p$ not $|\nabla u |_{L^p}^p$?
